# Understanding 「その中で私たちが思っていたのと違った答えだったのは。。。」

Tags: translation

Consider the following:

> **その中で私たちが思っていたのと違った答えだったのは、**「敬語はフェイクで、敬語を使わなかったら、人ともっと近くなれる」というのでした。

I'm having trouble understanding the beginning of this sentence. According to an auto-translator, it means the following:

> [image]

**Question:** Why does this translate to "**the only** answer that was different than what we were thinking was", as opposed to "**some responses** which were different than what we were thinking were..."?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The original text says nothing about the number of such responses. If there are multiple such responses, the following can be a perfectly correct translation.

> その中で私たちが思っていたのと違った答えだったのは、……でした。
>
> - Among them, responses that were different than what we were thinking included A, B, and C.
> - One of the answers that were different from what we had expected was A.

When translating Japanese text into English, (machine-)translators often have to make a guess about the number of things or implied subjects. The less context given, the more mistakes they make.